# Hibernate or Application Server JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Glassfish in production and OpenEJB in testing. I'm using JPA 1.0. I'm using Hibernate, but no specific Hibernate features, just standard JPA.

Hibernate is redundant in this collection and should be removed, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both OpenEJB and Glassfish deliver a JPA implementation. So in order to run you're application you don't need hibernate.

**But**, JPA implementation can and do behave differently in certain corner cases. Thus there is no 100% guarantee your application will be running correctly in production if you don’t run you’re application during tests with the same JPA implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes always include external dependencies if you really need it. Even if you want to go out of JPA spec then try to use EclipseLink as this is what comes bundled with Glassfish and is also the reference impl for JPA 2.0

Comment: JAP or JPA????? (Sorry about the number of question marks, but I have to have X amount of characters before allowing to publish comment)

Answer (score 2):

No. You still need Hibernate.

JPA is just an API specification. You need something to provide an implementation for that API. OpenEJB doesn't include that; Glassfish includes an implementation called EclipseLink, but in my opinion it's not as good as Hibernate.

Comment: This is incorrect, OpenEJB does bundle a JPA implementation (OpenJPA) or it wouldn't be able to provide JPA and CMP persistence.

Answer (score 1):

> Hibernate is redundant in this collection and should be removed, am I right?

GlassFish 3 uses EclipseLink as the default persistence provider (just in case, note that you can install an add-on to use [Hibernate as JPA provider on GlassFish](http://blogs.oracle.com/GlassFishPersistence/entry/using_hibernate_as_jpa_provider) if you want). 
[OpenEJB bundles OpenJPA](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/openjpa.html) as default persistence provider.

So if you are running all your JPA code (including tests) in-container (embedded or not), then you're not *forced* to keep Hibernate in your stack.

Actually, whether you're running your JPA code in-container or not, my suggestion would be to use the JPA implementation of the target platform everywhere (yes, the theory says that you should be able to use any JPA implementation but in practice, you don't want to face a provider specific bug in production that you didn't detect during testing because you were using another implementation).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether OpenEJB has an ORM provider, but assuming it hasn't you're not right. JPA is an API (stands for Java Persistence API) and not an implementation. Hibernate has an implementation for JPA. Look at a call stack when you use, for instance, `entityManager.persist`. This JPA call goes via Hibernate-Entity Manager to the Hibernate core. So you need Hibernate for JPA to work.

Comment: As far as I understand OpenEJB implements JPA (http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/jpa-concepts.html), right?

Comment: Hibernate is one of the JPA 2.0 providers and NOT the reference implementation of JPA 2.0. EclipseLink is the reference implementation

Comment: Well, I didn't write JPA 2.0, but I corrected my answer accordingly.